# MySQL Table not repairing

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, myisam

Table info:

```
Database name: user_motiva
Table name: wp_options.frm  wp_options.MYD  wp_options.MYI  wp_options.TMD
```

when I do a mysqlcheck -r --all-databases it gets hung on that table even if you let it sit all day.

Is there anther way to fix/repair/recover that table?

Should I use myisamchk? I saw something like:

```
shell> myisamchk --recover City
```

My config on a 16GB ram box

```
 cat /etc/my.cnf
[mysqld]
default-storage-engine=MyISAM
local-infile=0
symbolic-links=0
skip-networking
max_connections = 500
max_user_connections = 20
key_buffer = 512M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 64M
join_buffer_size = 64M
read_buffer_size = 12M
sort_buffer_size = 12M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 12M
table_cache = 2048
thread_cache_size = 16K
wait_timeout = 30
connect_timeout = 15
tmp_table_size = 64M
max_heap_table_size = 64M
max_allowed_packet = 64M
max_connect_errors = 10
query_cache_limit = 1M
query_cache_size = 64M
query_cache_type = 1
low_priority_updates=1
concurrent_insert=ALWAYS
log-error=/var/log/mysql/error.log
tmpdir=/home/mysqltmp
myisam_repair_threads=4
[mysqld_safe]
open_files_limit = 8192
log-error=/var/log/mysql/error.log

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 512M

[myisamchk]
key_buffer = 64M
sort_buffer = 64M
read_buffer = 16M
write_buffer = 16M
```

and could this have happened because of a crashed table from doing killall -9 mysqld because it would not shutdown and restart?

### EDIT:

```
root@server [/var/lib/mysql/user_motiva]# myisamchk -e *.MYI
Checking MyISAM file: wp_options.MYI
Data records:    1827   Deleted blocks:       3
myisamchk: warning: 3 clients are using or haven't closed the table properly
- check file-size
- check record delete-chain
- check key delete-chain
- check index reference
- check data record references index: 1
- check data record references index: 2
- check records and index references
MyISAM-table 'wp_options.MYI' is usable but should be fixed
root@server [/var/lib/mysql/user_motiva]# myisamchk --safe-recover wp_options.MYI
- recovering (with keycache) MyISAM-table 'wp_options.MYI'
Data records: 1827
myisamchk: error: Can't create new tempfile: 'wp_options.TMD'
MyISAM-table 'wp_options.MYI' is not fixed because of errors
Try fixing it by using the --safe-recover (-o), the --force (-f) option or by not using the --quick (-q) flag
root@ns2 [/var/lib/mysql/user_motiva]# myisamchk -o -f wp_options.MYI
- recovering (with keycache) MyISAM-table 'wp_options.MYI'
Data records: 1827
```

**Does this mean that it is now fixed? If so how do I move it back? (this was done on a different server)
Is there a way to maybe bring MySQL down on the main server and run a command to fix all the files?**

Answer (score 2):

> could this have happened because of a crashed table from doing killall -9 mysqld because it would not shutdown and restart?

Absolutely.  If you kill -9 mysqld and you're using `MyISAM` tables, you're almost guaranteed to crash some tables unless the server is really, really, really not busy... although the definition of a "crashed" table isn't as catastrophic as it sounds in all cases... it only means, at the simplest level, that the table is not in the state that it should have been in had the server closed it properly.

> Is there anther way to fix/repair/recover that table?

Have you been through the steps covered in [How to Repair MyISAM Tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/myisam-repair.html)?

Also, consider these things, which may give you some ideas that could get you on a faster path to recovery if they are not familiar concepts:

- With MyISAM tables, *everything* is in the files.  You could literally take your wp_options.* files (assuming for the sake of discussion that they were not crashed), copy them into a database directory on another MySQL server, `SHOW TABLES` and you would find that your table is visible and available on that other server.  For future recovery, if you had a slave server, you could shut it down and copy this table's files directly from there back to the master and be back online.  (This is only true for `MyISAM` and `ARCHIVE`, not `InnoDB`, but by contrast, `InnoDB` tables are extremely immune from this sort of corruption due to a hard/forced shutdown).
- The `myisamchk` utility is not technically a part of the actual MySQL Server itself -- it is a standalone utility built from many of the same underlying libraries, but can be used on a different computer, even without MySQL server installed.  The [`myisamchk`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/myisamchk.html) utility has various capabilities and levels of aggression.
- You could, therefore, stop MySQL, copy the table files to a different machine -- one with a nice speedy SSD, for example, could make a big difference in recovery time -- and repair the files with `myisamchk`, then (with the MySQL server stopped again) copy the table files back.  If you have other things running on your MySQL server, you could bring those other things back online while not bogging the server down with this repair.

By contrast, [`mysqlcheck`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqlcheck.html) is nothing but a simple program that connects to your MySQL server using the client libraries and...

> ...uses the SQL statements `CHECK TABLE`, `REPAIR TABLE`, `ANALYZE TABLE`, and `OPTIMIZE TABLE` in a convenient way for the user.

...so while the two utilities use many of the same methods to repair the tables, they are also fundamentally very different.

Answer (score 0):

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/myisamchk-memory.html  for various tunables related to the amount of memory allocated to myisam check.  Most notable is the myisam_sort_buffer_size param.  The more memory you can throw at this the better.  If you can give this one or more GB this will help speed things along.

mysqlcheck is designed to be running while mysqld is actually running.  myisamcheck will work directly against the .MY[ID] files on the file system.  This requires the mysqld first be shut down.

If you can take down the entire mysqld temporarily that will help free up additional memory you can feed to myisamcheck.

Assuming this is a dedicated mysql server with out any other services running I'd give myisamcheck 4 gigs of ram for the myisam_sort_buffer_size.

Running it with --force --recover will start rebuilding the table right away instead of just reporting it finds a problem with the broken table.  If you want more screen action as to the progress it's making you can run with -v, -vv or -vvv to ramp up the verbosity of the progress.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue today, one of my client's Joomla site hosted at bluehost. Two days ago he informed me that their site has been hacked, they just uploaded maintenance.html & shared required credentials with me.

After some research I found that almost 10 tables were crashed. I used Repair DB option from cPanel, repair report show following logs:

```
[db.jml_extensions] error: Can't create new tempfile: './db/jml_extensions.TMD'
[db.jml_extensions] status: Operation failed
```

I study [Why do MySQL tables crash? How do I prevent it?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15075/why-do-mysql-tables-crash-how-do-i-prevent-it) and found that db engine is ***MyISAM*** I tried to alter to ***InnoDB*** but getting this error:

```
[db.jml_finder_tokens] note: The storage engine for the table doesn't support repair
```

facing more problems then I rename all crashed tables & follow these steps:

1. Access phpMyAdmin and select the Joomla database from the left-hand
   panel
2. Select the jml_users table (or whatever table needs repaired)
3. Select Operations from the horizontal bottom menu
4. Select Repair table
   [image]

Now It repaired like a magic then I rename tables back to their original name & site get up.