# SQL: SOS: MySQL indexes overloads disk

Tags: mysql

My server is down now, 'couse indexes of 84GB DB are overloads disc.

Here is output of `df-h`:

```
/dev/ploop58097p1     193G  187G   16M 100% /
tmpfs                 2,0G     0  2,0G   0% /lib/init/rw
tmpfs                 2,0G  4,0K  2,0G   1% /dev/shm
```

DB retuns `#1030 - Got error 28 from storage engine` every time.
I can login in phpmyadmin, but don't know how to delete indexes of tables.

Comment: free some space, and drop some indexes. You can check with pt-duplicate-key-checker if you have any redundant indexes.

Comment: PMA don't work too. Output from PT-DUPLICATE-KEY-CHECKER: `mysql> # Size Duplicate Indexes   438610236
mysql> # Total Duplicate Indexes  88
mysql> # Total Indexes            1614`

Comment: Dropping indexes does not free up the space. It simply marks the indexes as deleted. Attempting to run `OPTIMIZE TABLE` requires space for temp table operation.

Comment: @akuzminsky is correct. Free some space. Do you some binary logs that can be deleted ? Can `/var/log/messages` be truncated ? Do you have any uncompressed mysqldumps that can be deleted ?

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA if my table is 14,8GB, how much free space I need?

Comment: Almost that same amount of space. BTW is the table MyISAM or InnoDB ?

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA MyISAM. Just freed 81GB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am glad you mentioned the table was MyISAM.

You can now run this

```
OPTIMIZE TABLE mytable;
```

on the 14.8G table.

So why did you get `#1030 - Got error 28 from storage engine` ?

It wasn't so much the indexes in themselves. Sometimes, a temp table may need to be written to disk. If there is no space for the temp table on disk, mysqld will not crash. It will freeze until space becomes available. I wrote about this before:

- `Apr 05, 2013` : ["Site Offline" MySQL server failing to start and stop](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39337/site-offline-mysql-server-failing-to-start-and-stop/39367#39367)
- `Mar 15, 2012` : [Why do MySQL tables crash? How do I prevent it?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15075/why-do-mysql-tables-crash-how-do-i-prevent-it/15079#15079)

If you want to compress every table regardless of storage engine, run this code in a script

```
MYSQL_USER=root
MYSQL_PASS=password
MYSQL_CONN="-u${MYSQL_USER} -p ${MYSQL_PASS}"
echo "SET SQL_LOG_BIN = 0;" > /tmp/CompressTables.sql
SQL="SELECT CONCAT('OPTIMIZE TABLE ',table_schema,'.',table_name,';')"
SQL="${SQL} FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema NOT IN')"
SQL="${SQL} ('information_schema','mysql','performance_schema')"
mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} -ANe"${SQL}" > /tmp/CompressTables.sql
less /tmp/CompressTables.sql
```

If the file looks good to you, run this

```
mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} -A < /tmp/CompressTables.sql
```

If all your tables are huge, run this over the weekend

Comment: @RonaldoMySQLDBA thank you very much! can you say me how I can optimize this table for search, and how I can optimize my DB?

Comment: You should post that as a separate question

Comment: @RonaldoMySQLDBA I already [posted](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/77654/sql-how-to-optimize-a-82gb-myisam-database) this